# Extraer variable de un bucle

Tags: python, python-3.x

En mi código hay un bucle, dentro del mismo, hay una variable `mid` que me está imprimiendo mientras el bucle se ejecuta:

```
print(ini, end="")
with open(r"a.txt", 'r+') as ff:
    for line in ff:
        fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", line)
        if fn:
            ffn = (fn.group(1))
            contador = + 1
            a = (''.join(map(str, (ffn))))
            mid = ("SYNQPI0SYNQFN{} ".format(a))
            print(mid, end="")
print(fin)
```

Output correcto:

```
STX010000qrqQSZ3SYNQPI0SYNQFN1673257 SYNQPI0SYNQFN1078961 SYNEOT??ETX
```

Quiero sacar la variable `mid` o llamarla fuera de codigo, pero el problema es que si le digo que imprima fuera del bucle, no me imprime todos los valores que quiero.

Output incorrecto:

```
STX010000qrqQSZ3 SYNQPI0SYNQFN1078961 SYNEOT??ETX
```

Quisiera tener un print(ini,mid,fin) fuera del bucle y que se me imprima correctamente.

Comment: Si te estoy entendiendo bien, lo que sucede es que la variable `mid` va cambiando de valor dentro del bucle, y al salir del mismo por tanto contiene sólo el valor de la última iteración y tú querrías tener "todos" los valores por los que ha ido pasando. Eso lo puedes resolver creando una lista vacía fuera del bucle y añadiendo a ella (con `lista.append()`) cada valor de `mid` dentro del bucle. Al salir tendrás todos los elementos en esa lista y podrás mostrarlos con `print(" ".join(lista))`

Comment: era lo que buscaba, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `generador`, una función que usa `yield` en lugar de `return`

```
def extractor():
    with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r+') as ff:
        for line in ff:
            fn = re.search(r"FFN(\d+)", line)
            if fn:
                ffn = (fn.group(1))
                contador = + 1
                a = (''.join(map(str, (ffn))))
                mid = ("SYNQPI0SYNQFN{} ".format(a))
                yield mid
```

Conservamos lo central del código (sin los `print`) y cada vez que obtenemos un nuevo `mid`, lo retornamos con `yield`, sin perder el contexto en que se obtuvo, por lo que la iteración puede continuar desde donde quedo.

El generador se comporta como un iterador ordinario, por lo que se puede poner en un `for`:

```
ini = "INI"
fin = "FIN"
for mid in extractor():
    print(ini, mid, fin)
```

produce:

```
INI SYNQPI0SYNQFN1025309  FIN
INI SYNQPI0SYNQFN1025824  FIN
```